# Angular Ionic data binding

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm looping a list of products, and I want to get un single product to make HTTP request with IDProduct but i can't pass prod from .html to .ts. Is anyone can help Me ?

```
       <ion-item *ngFor="let prod of listProdotti | filter:searchItem">
          <ion-label>{{ prod.NomeProdotto }}</ion-label>
          <ion-label>{{ prod.Reference }}</ion-label>
          <ion-toggle color="primary" [checked]="prod.Pubblicato == 'Si' ? true: false" (ionChange)="statusProduct($event)"></ion-toggle>
          <ion-icon style="cursor: pointer;"name="trash" color="danger" (click)="deleteProduct(prod.IDProdotto, prod.NomeProdotto)"></ion-icon>
       </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is that the `click` event is not working on the `ion-icon`.
Try wrapping the `ion-icon` inside the button.

```html
    <button ion-button icon-only (click)="deleteProduct(prod.IDProdotto, prod.NomeProdotto)">
        <ion-icon style="cursor: pointer;"name="trash" color="danger"></ion-icon>
    </button>
```

Comment: Everything is working, but i don't know how to pass prod.IDProdotto when i click in <ion-toggle> to .ts file

Comment: I have found a solution, thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess misunderstood your question. I suggest you post the solution in case someone has the same problem.